# Get mutool to output "structured text (as xml)"

Tags: pdf, mupdf, structured-text

Following mutool's instructions for the `draw` command
https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-draw.html

How do I output "structured text (as xml)" when one of the output "vector formats" is "debug trace (as xml)" and the "output format is inferred from the output filename" ?

If I run

```
mutool draw -o "testfile.xml" "testfile.pdf"
```

it appears that I get the "debug trace (as xml)" file format.

What file extension should I use to ensure that the "structured text (as xml)" format is output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage message if you run "mutool draw" with no arguments tells you which formats are supported, and what their file extensions are.

In your case, you want "stext" output.

```
mutool draw -o out.stext input.pdf
mutool draw -F stext -o out.xml input.pdf
```

Or if you prefer the "mutool convert" command, which supports advanced output options using the -O argument.

```
mutool convert -o out.stext input.pdf
```